# Why can't my Laravel script use variables in sending mail

Tags: email, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.x and have a controller script that sends email. If my recipient parameters are hard coded, the script works.

```
$email_data = array('inv_no' => '12345');

Mail::send('view.emailbody', $email_data, function($message) {
  $message->to('johndoe@abc.com', 'ABC Co')->subject('Invoice');
});
```

But if I use variables on recipient parameters, my script does not work.

```
$email_data = array('inv_no' => '12345');
$company_email = 'johndoe@abc.com';
$company_name = 'ABC Co';

Mail::send('view.emailbody', $email_data, function($message) {
  $message->to($company_email, $company_name)->subject('Invoice');
});
```

I really can't figure out where my error is.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass those variable then it will work as follows:

```
$email_data = array('inv_no' => '12345');
$company_email = 'johndoe@abc.com';
$company_name = 'ABC Co';

Mail::send('view.emailbody', $email_data, function($message) use ($company_email, $company_name) {
  $message->to($company_email, $company_name)->subject('Invoice');
});
```

Comment: Hello Hasan, I tried the code and it worked! Thanks :-)

Comment: I've clicked the arrow above the numeral 0 besides your answer, but get a notify that I need 15 reputation :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work -- have a look plz :)

Comment: Got it. I've marked/ ticked your answer as correct. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

For some (strange) reason, if the recipient parameters are coming from form submit entries, the script works

```
$email_data = array('inv_no' => '12345');

Mail::send('view.emailbody', $email_data, function($message) {
  $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('company-name'))->subject('Invoice');
});
```